# IFormFile is null value when uploading file from postman

Tags: file, asp.net-web-api, request

I tried to test uploading an IFormFile through postman to web API and the error shows the IFormFile is a null value

```
  [HttpPost]
  
        public void Post([FromForm] Product product,IFormFile file)
        {
            var imagePath = Path.Combine(_hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images", file.FileName);
            var streamImage = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Create);
            file.CopyTo(streamImage);
            var prod = new Product
            {
               Name = product.Name,
                Description=product.Description,
                Price=product.Price,
                BasePrice=product.BasePrice,
                Image=imagePath,
                CategoryId = product.CategoryId,
            };
            _repository.AddProduct(prod);
        }
```

Postman request
[image]
[image]

The respsonse shows that my IFromFile is a null value but I am not able to find out where did I miss.
Can you  help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
public void Post([FromForm] Product product, IFormFile file)
```

Needs to be changed to this:

```
public void Post(
    [FromForm] Product product, [FromForm(Name = "Image")] IFormFile file)
```

Your Postman shows the form's file property name as `"Image"` *not* `"file"`. Your parameter name *must* match the Form name (case-insensitive).

You could also do this:

```
public void Post([FromForm] Product product, [FromForm] IFormFile image)
```